# Google AdWords Transfers in Big Query: Possible to Change Table Schema?

Tags: google-bigquery, google-ads-api

I started to test Google AdWords transfers for Big Query (https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/adwords-transfer).

I have few questions for which I cannot find answers anywhere.

Is it possible to e.g. edit which columns are downloaded from AdWords to Big Query? E.g. Keyword report has only ad group ID column but not ad group text name.

Or is it possible to decide which tables=reports are downloaded? The transfer creates around 60 tables and I need just 5...

DZ

Answer (score 0):

According to [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/adwords-transfer#setting_up_an_adwords_data_transfer), AdWords data transfer
store your AdWords data into a Dataset. So, the inputs are in terms of Adwords customer IDs (minimum one customer ID) and the output is a collection of Datasets. 
I think, you need a modified version of [PubSub](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/overview#types) to store special columns or tables in BigQuery.